# Getting data from two coordinating foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a foreach loop for fetching arrays of date and storing it in a table.

I implemented it just fine. Until i included the data of each array of dates.

here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gubot.png) of the screen shot.

the first array always repeats itself up until the end of every data.

here is my code.

```php
<? php

  foreach($array_date as $valuez => $values) {

?>

<? php foreach($appointment as $item => $value) { ?>

<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <?php echo $values; ?>
  </th>

  <td scope="row" title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?></td>
  <td title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo $value->{'doctor'}->{'id'}; ?></td>
  <td title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo count($value->{'prescriptions'}->{'prescriptions'}); ?></td>

<? php

    }

?>

</tr>


<? php

  }

?>
```

as you can see in the screenshot. the first date (2015-11-23) was repeated until the last data. then shifted to the second date (2015-11-25). the needed output is that the first array date(2015-11-23) is only displayed once in its respective data(prescription no. = 372), and the second array data(2015-11-25) in its data(prescription no. = 388) and so on...

i am new in using nested foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what's not working?

Comment: what's your question? You don't want the first row?

Comment: Can you give us a complete example, with an array you want taken apart?  Because it could be the array.

Comment: Btw.. why are you doing this: `$value->{'id'};` instead of just `$value->id;`? Curly braces are only necessary if you use a variable as property name, like: `$value->{$somevar};`.

Comment: i have added an explanation for you to further understand my problem. thanks!

Comment: Seems like the second foreach is unnessecary if you only want the first item in the `$appointment` array. Just use `$appointment[0]->id`etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a multidimensional array. You have two coordinating arrays. (It would be helpful to include the contents of the $appointment array.)

Assuming that the $appointment array has the same numeric indices as the $array_date array, you could do it this way, with only one loop:

```
<? php foreach($appointment as $item => $value) { ?>

<tr>
  <th scope="row">
    <?php echo $array_date[$item]; ?>
  </th>

  <td scope="row" title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?></td>
  <td title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo $value->{'doctor'}->{'id'}; ?></td>
  <td title="View details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#presc-from-<?php echo $value->{'id'}; ?>">
    <?php echo count($value->{'prescriptions'}->{'prescriptions'}); ?></td>

</tr>

<? php

    }

?>
```